# PHP to AWS S3 multipart upload always fails

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

Trying to upload a 7G file to S3 using the PHP SDK v2 (PHP 5.5 not available).  File uploads less than 5G work great, but multipart uploads have never worked.  They always end with no message or error at all, just before the upload should complete.

I have full S3 access.  Have tried a bunch of different things to no avail.

**Code is nothing special:**

```
$uploader = UploadBuilder::newInstance()
    ->setBucket($bucket_nm)
    ->setKey($key)
    ->setMinPartSize(100 * 1024 * 1024)
    ->setConcurrency(1)
    ->setSource($src_path)
    ->setClient($s3)
    ->build();
try {
    $uploader->getEventDispatcher()->addListener(
      'multipart_upload.after_part_upload',
      function($event) {
            $msg = $event['state']->count() . ' parts uploaded.';
            echo "$msg<br />";
            WriteToLog($msg);
      }
    );
    $uploader->upload();
    $msg = 'Upload complete.';
} catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
    $uploader->abort();
    $msg = 'Upload failed. ' . $e->getMessage() . '.';
}
echo "$msg<br />";
WriteToLog($msg);
```

Comment: Execution always fails silently, bypassing `register_shutdown_function`.

Appears to be a problem with cURL multi. Usually, execution ends just before uploading the last group of parts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place apply these try catch in place of your for abort or upload process

```
// Perform the upload. Abort the upload if something goes wrong
try {
$uploader->upload();
echo "Upload complete.\n";
} catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
$uploader->abort();
echo "Upload failed.\n";
}
```